# What would replacement level fertility have to be for a species with a gestation of 10 years?

Tags: science-based

In my world, I have a species that takes 10 years to produce children. Once they are born, they become sexually mature after 2 years. With this in mind, what would the replacement rates need to be to sustain a stable population?

Comment: More data needed. How many of them die before reaching adulthood? (BTW: what's the tech level?)

Comment: Stable population means that natality equals mortality. You need to specify what the mortality rate is.

Comment: The replacement rate is how many children need to be born to each individual (on average) to balance the natural death rate. To find that, you need to know how many die before reaching maturity: high infant mortality, for instance, means the replacement rate is higher (for reference, it's about 2.1 in modern developed countries). A long gestation relative to the span of fertile years can obviously impact the maximum number of births per person, but it's not directly connected to the replacement level. Without information on your society's typical mortality rates, we can't answer your question.

Comment: There is no relationship between the length of the gestation and the number of daughters each female must have in order to keep the population stable. Basically, each female must have one daughter to replace her, plus as many daughters needed to offset mortality before sexual maturity (that's abaout 0.02 daughters in modern humans in civilized countries) plus how many sons are culturally necessary; culturally, because biologically males don't count for much.

Comment: Of course if they produce litters of 400 to 500 at a time, there'd be presumably a balance that many died before achieving reproductive potential. If there's a usual maximum P of 5 per female in their lifetime, then they'd need to survive in proportionally greater numbers.

Comment: I think this may have been a question asked without an understanding of all the factors that control the outcome. That said, the answer this question did receive is very useful and I'm inclined to change my original question to better reflect that if it's allowed.

Comment: Usually you should be care full with editing a question, because edits might invalidate answers. Normally questions are edited to give extra details (I guess here the case) that were asked for, to make the question better answerable. If you do a major addition or edit note it in the question so that if your edit invalidates answers it is clear they may have been given before the edit. If the edit is so major that it basically changes the hearth of the question I think you are better of writing a new question.

Answer (score 5):

So a population is stable if on average every member produces **1** offspring that itself will reproduce. The only factor you need to take into account is the average death rate before reproduction has happened. Seeing that it takes 10 years to produce a child this might be slightly higher than normal species, but on the other hand a lot lower than insects for example.

So you would need a average child reproduction rate of
$$ N = 1 + \frac{P_{d}}{P_0} \text{,}$$
where N is the average number of children per parent, Pd is the number of the member species that die before bearing a child at a specific time and P0 is the total population at that time. So you can fill in the fraction Pd/P0 of the members that die before creating a child.

So you see that if nobody dies before they produce a child the fraction will be 0 (since Pd = 0) and every member of the species needs to produce 1 child. If half of you population dies (Pd = 1/2*P0) before having a child your fraction will be 1/2 so every member that does not die needs to produce 1.5 children.

NOTE: That this is a rough but very easy formula which is not entirely accurate. It assumes that your population is already at a stable population and it ignores the fact that Pd should be adjusted for N. For more accurate formula's look into the population growth formula's. [Population Growth Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_growth#:%7E:text=Population%20growth%20is%20the%20increase,to%207.9%20billion%20in%202020.)

Comment: +1. A very specific answer to a very vague question.